# New line character is appended when a image is downloaded from url

Tags: java, url, download, inputstream

We are trying to download an image file from url https://test.com/images/123.jpg

```
URL url = new URL("https://test.com/images/123.jpg");

InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
pResponse.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
pResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""123.jpg\"");

while ((inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    pResponse.getOutputStream().write(buffer);
}
pResponse.getOutputStream().flush();
pResponse.getOutputStream().close();

inputStream.close();
```

The downloaded file is corrupted. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SXbe.jpg) for screenshot. When I tried to open the file with Notepad++, a empty line is appended at the beginning of the file.

On saving the file by removing the empty line at the beginning of the file, We are able to open the image successfully.

When I changed the code and not writing the bytes to pResponse.getOutputStream() then the image downloaded has an empty line.

So, How can we remove that empty line or reset the output stream to empty

Please correct me if I am wrong

Regards,

John

Comment: It returns a 404

Comment: it is an actual url or just example. if it is actual then it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why empty line is getting appended, but when tries to create the same scenario of downloading a file i used this code and it is working fine:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/HTMLCS/Images/OCR.PNG");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\RegressionTests\\OCR.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
```

It may or may not be helpful to you but you should give it a try.
Please do let me know if i was not able to understand your question correctly.